# Image list not displaying with ajax call in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My images list not displaying when i call images with ajax call . on page load code work perfectly but on ajax call it did not display any images list my code is.

The view markup is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".yesterdayfilter").click(function () {
      
        var username = $("#users-ddl option:selected").text();
        alert(username);

        $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: "/Home/index",
               dataType: 'image/jpg',
               data: {
                 Username: username,
                },
                success: function (status) {
                console.log('Send');
                },
                 error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }
                });

                });

                });
               </script>
```

The code where image display in view:

```
          <div class="flex items-center" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#superlarge-modal-size- 
           preview">
                    @{
                        if (Session["recentscreenshotss"] != null)
                        {
                            var screenshotslist = 
       
       
   (List<ezilineezitaskernew.Models.sp_getrecentscreenshots_Result>)Session["recentscreenshotss"];
                            if (screenshotslist != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in screenshotslist)
                                {

                                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-12 xl:col-span-12 mt-8">
                                        <div class="flex-justifiy flex-wrap">
                                            <div class="w-24 h-24 relative image-fit mb-5 mr-5 cursor-pointer zoom-in">
                                                <button value="@item.Image" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basic-modal-preview" class="testing"><img class="rounded-md" alt="Midone Tailwind HTML Admin Template" src="@item.Image"></button>
                                                <div class="tooltip w-5 h-5 flex items-center justify-center absolute rounded-full text-white bg-theme-6 right-0 top-0 -mr-2 -mt-2 tooltipstered"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x w-4 h-4"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg> </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </div>
```

The controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string Username)
    {
        GetOffices();
        SetLogo();

        var Userid = dbcontext.USERS.Where(x => x.Username == Username).FirstOrDefault();
        int UID = Userid.Id;
        int companyid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["company-id"]);
        var screenshotlist = dbcontext.sp_getrecentscreenshots(null, null, companyid).ToList();

        int s_startId = screenshotlist[0].Id;
        int s_lastId = s_startId + 6;

        if (screenshotlist != null)
        {
            var screenshots = dbcontext.sp_getrecentscreenshots(s_startId, s_lastId, 
            companyid).ToList();
            Session["recentscreenshotss"] = screenshots;
        }
      }
```

The code is fine . only issue is that it is not displaying images . the same code work when page load but not working with ajax call can anyone help me?

Comment: your ajax success is not doing any job except log:
`success: function (status) {console.log('Send');  },` maybe your forgot to add some code there.

Answer (score 0):

there is different solution to your problem:

solution 1:

On ajax success you can reload page with the Username as parameter

---

solution 2 :

`.empty()` and `.append` your `<div>` on ajax success with your `<div>` content

---

solution 3 :

The cleanest solution:

- Put your `<div>` content in a partial view named for example Searchpartial.cshtml
- Add an empty  in your current view and give it the an id for example `<div id="divSearch"></div>`

and load it with your button as follow with GET:

```
$("#divSearch").empty()
$.get("/Home/Searchpartial", { Username: 'username' },
    function (result) {
        $("#divSearch").append(result);
    }
);
```

In your controller need to call your partial view as follow:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Searchpartial(string Username)
{

    // your code

    return PartialView("Searchpartial");
}
```

I see that your controller HTTP Post is pointing to Index in your ajax I notice it was index be careful for case sensitive.

Comment: is page reload is necessary . i want without page load.

Comment: so you have to use solution 3